# Reference 'django.contrib.auth.urls' to custom specific templates

Tags: django

I wrote specific templates to deal with password reset and change,
the file tree structures as:

```
In [3]: !tree /Users/me/desktop/Django/forum/user/templates
/Users/me/desktop/Django/forum/user/templates
├── registration
│   ├── logged_out.html
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── password_change_done.html
│   ├── password_reset_complete.html
│   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
│   ├── password_reset_done.html
│   └── password_reset_form.html
└── user
    ├── activate.html
    ├── failure.html
    ├── register.html
    ├── success.html
    └── validate.html
```

The project `urls` is configured as:

```
# Project url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^$", views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^article/', include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
    url(r'^user/', include('user.urls',namespace='user')),
    url(r'^user/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Unfortunately, when I try to issue request as `http://127.0.0.1:8001/user/password_reset/`,
the browser redirect to its default admin site

[image]
I am working on Django 1.11

How reference `'django.contrib.auth.urls'` to my own templates?

Comment: have you written your own views for password reset, change urls?. Anyway, you have 2 urls for `r'^user/'`. The 2nd one will just override the first one and I believe that is why you see admin page. Remove the 2nd one and you should see your custom view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to override admin templates, you can just add `admin` directory and templates in your template dir.

It's well explained in django official docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

If you want to override view either, you have to make your own app and match it to urls.

Comment: ty but I did not want to override admin site, I intent to employ its views and urls to my own app.

Comment: Then you can make your own apps - then it means you don't have to override auth, you just make your own view and urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass template_name as variable...:

in urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/login-custom-template/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'path-to-custom-template.html'}, name='login-custom'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To ref to your template, in case it doesn't work just use template name:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'change-password/',
        auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='change-password.html'),
    ),
]
```

OR:

Even skip `django.contrib.auth.urls` if you want to use another directory template not in registration, in this case I point to template `/basic_app/`

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

AND

```
re_path(r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='basic_app/login.html'),name='login')
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the same problem while doing [this](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/) tutorial:

I discovered that You can skip 'admin' route described earlier and just move Your users app above other apps in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # External apps
    'taggit',
    # My apps
    'projekty',
    'blog',
]
```